# How to use a CommandMenu within a CommandGroup?

Tags: swiftui

I would like to create a menu at the import/export location.

```
CommandGroup(replacing: CommandGroupPlacement.importExport) {
       CommandMenu("Import"){
                Button("Format I (.f1)"){
                    print("import Format 1")
                }
                Button ("Format II (.f2)") {
                    print("import Format 2")
                }
            }
        }
```

Unfortunately, `CommandMenu` isn't a `View` but a `Command`. So, how do I combine these two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following

```
CommandGroup(replacing: CommandGroupPlacement.importExport) {
    Menu("Import") {                                            // << here !!
            Button("Format I (.f1)"){
                print("import Format 1")
            }
            Button ("Format II (.f2)") {
                print("import Format 2")
            }
        }
    }
```